# Output text in textfield not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, uitextview

I'm just trying to simply get the input from a textfield to show up in a textview after pressing a button but it keeps crashing my app. This is my code so far.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var searchBar: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textOut: UITextView!

    @IBAction func clearAction() {
        textOut.text = ""
    }

    @IBAction func backgroundTouched(_ sender: UIControl) {
        textOut.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    @IBAction func editEnded(_ sender: UITextField) {
        sender.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    @IBAction func searchPress(_ sender: UIButton) {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        textOut.text = searchBar.text
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question with details about the error. Include the complete error and point out which line is causing the error.

Comment: The error I'm getting says "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM resignFirstResponder]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17424be50'" and it has to do with the function searchPress and how I'm handling the .resignFirstResponder()

Comment: As I said, please [edit] your question.

Comment: change this line to 
searchBar.resignFirstResponder() with
self.view.endEditing(true)

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work

Comment: @Clarke Roche check you outlet connection is connected properly and you have not given 2 outlet for same connection in storyboard.

Comment: I've checked the outlet connections, it's not the problem

Comment: please upload connection image

Answer (score 0):

`searchBar.text` is an optional value that you need to unwrap.  The issue also may arise from the fact that you are resigning your `textField` before accessing its text because `editEnded` is getting called before `searchPress`.  Attempt these solutions and let me know what happens.

Comment: I just tried that, force unwrapped searchBar.text and resigning textField, still get the same error